# How would I use Sass to give something a default but optionally overridable value?

Tags: css, variables, inheritance, sass, scope

I'd like to use Sass to create a reusable HTML snippet with default values, but then make those values optionally customizable. Let's say I'm making a button and I set up some base SCSS to make the button red by default like so:

```
%button-shared {
    $button-color: red;
    td {
        border-color: $button-color;
        color: $button-color;
        background-color: white;

        text-decoration: none;

        width: 50px;
        height: 15px;
        border-radius: 6px;
    }
}
```

I use a variable because I want it set in two different places. In this example, I want a white button with a colored outline that matches colored text like so:

[image]

Now let's say I give my two buttons in HTML different classes, button-one and button-two. Now I'd like to assign that SCSS to my two buttons, so I extend %button-shared to those two HTML classes. Except, I'd also like button-one to be a different color from the default red:

```
.button-one {
    $button-color: green;
    @extend %cta-shared;
}

.button-two {
    @extend %cta-shared;
}
```

Unfortunately, this implementation ends up with them both being red. How can I setup my SCSS to allow for easy overriding of of a variable?

Comment: Have you checked out the docs for default values with Sass? https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables#default-values

Comment: I was attempting to but couldn't get it to work. It seems like my use-case is a little different from what's described in the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use mix-ins: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin

```
@mixin button-shared($button-color: red) {
   td {
        background-color: white;
        border-color: $button-color;
        color: $button-color;

        text-decoration: none;

        width: 50px;
        height: 15px;
        border-radius: 6px;
    }
}

.button-one {
    @include button-shared(green);
}

.button-two {
    @include button-shared();
}
```

Comment: I thought this would be possible using only variable scoping and inheritance, but mixins work so I'll go with this!